# Retrieve data from remote server

Tags: java, xml, json

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve data (xml or json format) from remote web application and then to parse same data in Java?
Is there any way to pass url to remote host, get response and retrieve data in way suitable for further processing in Java?

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You would send an HTTP request, read its response, and parse it. This can be made using an [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29), or using a library like apache HttpCLient if you need more flexibility.

Comment: That is exactly what I've been looking for. Thanks a lot